# Checking for an empty JSON Key in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I'm working on an App that returns some JSON data that the user is searching for in a tableView. Sometimes there is an empty key that is returned and it seems to be crashing my app if a selection is choosin. I've looked up other solutions, but its still crashing regardless of how I set up my "if" check.

This first one is weird, it works but in the text view where the data is displayed "{}" is displayed instead of "Not Available..." Why?

```
if ([gameDetails objectForKey:@"description"] !=nil) {
    gameDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [gameDetails objectForKey:@"description"]];
}
else
{
    gameDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Available..."];
}
```

The next one crashes regardless of how I set it up.

```
if ([gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"] != nil) {
    NSURL *coverImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"]];
    NSData *imageLink = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:coverImage];
    coverArt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageLink];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No Photo");
}
```

Can someone tell me why these are causing my app to keep crashing? Let me know if I need more information.

Comment: In the 1st case you get an empty dictionary for the `description` key. In the 2nd case you don't mention the error but most likely you are getting an `NSNull` object.

Comment: can you print the crashing log here ?

Comment: for 2nd point 1st you have to do enscapeencoding url and then get data from URL. and you must check if you get data then only set image in imageview like if(imageLink)coverArt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageLink];

Comment: Rmaddy: Since I'm getting an empty dictionary for the description key, why is it putting {} instead of the text I want?

Comment: Because the output of `NSDictionary description` on an empty dictionary will be `{}`. BTW - when you wish to reply to a specific person, put the `@` symbol before their username.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. If I'm checking to see if my dictionary key is nil, why is it displaying an empty dictionary and not my string?

Comment: Because an empty dictionary isn't `nil`.

Comment: Would I want to check if it's NULL like other suggested for my 2nd problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSURL *coverImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"]];
```

// you have to check that coverImage is not nil then only you have to do following operation. else write some info regarding nil.

```
NSData *imageLink = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:coverImage];
coverArt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageLink];
```

// For checking nil or null you can use following code.

```
if([[itemDataDict valueForKey:@"ItemNo"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if([[itemDataDict valueForKey:@"ItemNo"] isEqualToString:@""] || [[itemDataDict valueForKey:@"ItemNo"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
        {
            txtItemNo.text = @"";
        }
        else
        {
            txtItemNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[itemDataDict valueForKey:@"ItemNo"]];
        }
    }
else
    {
        txtItemNo.text = @"";
    }
```

Let me know if you required more information.

Comment: Can this same solution be applied to my first problem? Since it's returning an empty dictionary not nil.

Comment: Yes you can apply this solution to check empty dictionary, need to change the condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes second time due to the line below

```
NSURL *coverImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"]];
```

and

```
if ([gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"] != nil)
```

Your if condition is not false always, sometime you get some other value like `(null)` or, `NSNull`, which is different from `nil` and the `NSURL` statement will crash if you supply anything other than `NSString`.

To avoid this condition you can have a check on `[gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"]` that what you are getting..

I suggest you can use some macro like below

```
#define IsEmpty(value) (value == (id)[NSNull null] || value == nil || ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ([value isEqualToString:@""] ||  [value isEqualToString:@"<null>"]))) ? YES : NO

#define IfNULL(original, replacement) IsNULL(original) ? replacement : original

#define IsNULL(original) original == (id)[NSNull null]

#define SafeString(value) IfNULL(value, @"")
```

and then use the check below

```
if (SafeString([gameDetails objectForKey:@"box_front"]).length != 0)
```

I hope it works.

Cheers.